# .class or .java used by wildfly server to show up the screen

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly

I have both a .class file and a .java file in my WAR. The .class file is the compiled version of the .java file.
I want to know which of these two files is used by the server to load the screen or any task that the file is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that java text code file has .java extension that are human readable java codes and .class is javabyte code file that is executable by java runtime machine(JVM) to execute java codes on host machine.The .class files generates by java compilers(search this words: JDK, OpenJDK)

please read this wiki page completely:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

also read link about JVM:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Web server and web application servers such Wildfly(JBOSS), Apache Tomcat, Oracle IBM Weblogic, Websphere, ... deploy your java project in different format such as WAR to manage and run your deployment on jvm. So, Web (application) servers do not need .java files to execute your project.

Comment: I am new in this field. Thank you for your answer.